# udev can't retrieve vendor id

Tags: linux, udev

I compiled and installed udev to my customized linux system with the following configuration.

```
--build=$(HostTuple) \
--host=$(TargetTuple) \
--disable-introspection \
--disable-gudev \
--enable-static \
--enable-shared \
--without-selinux \
--without-pci-ids-path \
--prefix=/usr \
--sysconfdir=/etc \
--sbindir=/sbin \
--libdir=/usr/lib \
--with-rootlibdir=/lib \
--libexecdir=/lib \
--localstatedir=/var
```

However, when I play with udev on my linux, it seems that udev cannot retrieve vendor and product information.

```
root@machine# udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/ttyACM0
P: /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1- 1:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
N: ttyACM0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyACM0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
E: MAJOR=166
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
```

But on my ubuntu, there are is detailed information

```
aa@bbs$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/ttyACM0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
N: ttyACM0
S: serial/by-id/usb-xxx_000000000000000-if00
S: serial/by-path/pci-0000:02:03.0-usb-0:3:1.0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-id/usb-xxx_000000000000000-if00 /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:02:03.0-usb-0:3:1.0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyACM0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
E: ID_BUS=usb
...
E: ID_VENDOR=xxx
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=xxx
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=xxx
E: MAJOR=166
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration of udev? Really appreciate it!

Comment: This probably belongs on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/, since it doesn't seem to relate directly to programming or programming tools.

Comment: @ajp15243 thank you for the comment. I will post there.

Comment: try `udevadm info -a /dev/ttyACM0` instead